# Can or should Task.async() be used in a controller#action?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Because `Task.async()` is linked to the current process, does this mean that if I use it in an action of a controller, it'll get killed automatically, or will die, once an action has been executed?

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.PageController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    
    # ????
    Task.async(fn -> some_10_second_long_stuff() end)
    Task.async(fn -> another_10_second_long_stuff() end)
    # will they both get killed or die?

    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
```

If so, what should be used instead? `Task.start()` ?

---

Those 2 `some_10_second_long_stuff` functions are "send emails"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sole purpose of [`Task.async/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async/1) would be to create a task that can easily be awaited.

Unless blown up, or killed (read: if it returns normally,) it just silently dies and surely it won’t do anything with the calling process. If the task dies abnormally, it would also result in a crash of the calling process.

It is all well described in the docs I linked above.

That said, if you want to spawn a task for side effects only, use [`Task.start/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#start/1). If you want the task to be monitored, and restarted, if crashed, use [`Task.start_link/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#start_link/1). If you need the task to be awaited by the controller process, use `Task.async/1`.

Comment: You say "if you want .... then use...". How should I know what I want? I want whichever will work and whichever is recommended by good practises **for this particular case** that I've described. Will it be `Task.start()` then?

Comment: You didn’t describe the case though. Should it run for side effects only or you’d need the result back? What should happen if the task crashes unexpectedly? Retry? Drop-and-forget? Log? Something else?

Comment: I've not thought about all those edge cases yet. Those 2 tasks will be "send emails". I think while I may use `Task.start()` there, it'd be better to remove that code from Controller, and instead to utilize `GenServer` to have it to scan unsent emails in background, from db, all the time and send them. (?)

Comment: Might be. It heavily depends on the application logic, but in general, yes, scanning unsent might be a good idea.

Comment: Depending of the use case, you might want to consider [`Task.Supervisor.start_child/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#start_child/3) so that the task is still attached to your supervision tree (but not through the calling process). From the [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#module-dynamically-supervised-tasks), "We encourage developers to rely on supervised tasks as much as possible."

Comment: @sabiwara and what advantage will that have?

Comment: This [discussion](https://elixirforum.com/t/when-are-agent-and-task-supervisor-useful/896/4) adds a bit on what is in the docs, but the main point is proper cleanup when the application stops. It also allows you to specify some [options](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#start_link/1) like `:max_children` to limit the concurrency of mails being sent at the same time, for instance. In general, starting processes outside of the supervision tree is [not recommended](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/library-guidelines.html#avoid-spawning-unsupervised-processes).

Answer (score 0):

> When a process terminates, it will terminate with an exit reason. This
> exit reason is emitted in an exit signal to all linked processes.
>
> The default behavior when a process receives an exit signal with an
> exit reason other than `normal`, is to terminate and in turn emit exit
> signals with the same exit reason to its linked processes. **An exit
> signal with reason `normal` is ignored.**

So, just because a process ends, does not necessarily mean that its linked processes will terminate.  Rather, a process has to crash to cause its linked processes to crash.  Even then, a linked process can "trap exits" to prevent it from crashing.

In the following example, a process starts a new process and links to it, then the original process ends because it has nothing more to do, i.e. the function has no more statements to execute, yet the linked process keeps executing:

```
defmodule A do

  def start do
    spawn(A, :do_stuff, []) 
  end

  def do_stuff do    #This is the "do_stuff() process"...
    spawn_link(A, :ticker, [10])   #...which spawns a second process, the "ticker()" process, and links to it.
    IO.puts "exiting do_stuff()"   #The "do_stuff()" process ends.  Does the "ticker()" process also end now?
  end

  def ticker(0), do: IO.puts "exiting ticker()" 
  def ticker(num_ticks) do
    :timer.sleep(1000)  #sleep for 1 second
    IO.write "."
    ticker(num_ticks - 1)
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> A.start
exiting do_stuff
:ok
..........exiting ticker()
iex(2)>
```

The output shows that the ticker() process continued executing for 10 seconds after the do_stuff() process terminated--see the ten dots?

Compare the output above to the output produced when you change do_stuff() to this:

```
 def do_stuff do
    spawn_link(A, :ticker, [10]) 

    :timer.sleep(2000)
    raise "I'm crashing"

    IO.puts "exiting do_stuff() normally"
  end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> A.start
:ok

..iex(2)> 
23:25:25.772 [error] Process #PID<0.116.0> raised an exception
** (RuntimeError) I'm crashing
    a.ex:20: A.do_stuff/0
```

This time there are only two dots.

**========= Response to comment**:

Here is an example that calls `Task.async` to run ticker():

```
defmodule A do

  def start do
    spawn(A, :do_stuff, [])
    :ok
  end

  def do_stuff do
    Task.async(A, :ticker, [10])

    #spawn_link(A, :ticker, [10])  #links the process executing do_stuff() and
    #:timer.sleep(2000)
    #raise "I'm crashing"

    IO.puts "exiting do_stuff() normally"
  end

  def ticker(0), do: IO.puts "exiting ticker()"
  def ticker(num_ticks) do
    :timer.sleep(1000)  #sleep for 1 second
    IO.write "."
    ticker(num_ticks - 1)
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> A.start
exiting do_stuff() normally
:ok
..........exiting ticker()
```

Notice the 10 dots, which means the "ticker() process" executed for 10 seconds after the "do_stuff() process" exited normally.

The Task docs say that you ***must*** call `Task.await()` if you call `Task.async()`, but there doesn't seem to be any penalty for not calling await().  I guess you get a message in the calling process's mailbox when Task.async() finishes executing, and if you launch a trillion Tasks, then you can overflow the mailbox and cause the process to crash.

Comment: `So, just because a process ends, does not necessarily mean that its linked processes will terminate. ` -- well, when I was using `Task.async()` that didn't work -- emails wouldn't get sent, nor delivered successfully. Then I switched to `Task.start()`, and they began to get sent and delivered. How would you explain this?

Comment: I can't explain your code.  When I modify my example to call `Task.async()` inside the "do_stuff() process" and run ticker() in the Task, ticker() keeps executing after the "do_stuff()" process exits.  See the additional example I posted at the end of my answer.